# Wordpress: Conditional tag in css for div background image?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, conditional-statements

For the meta-data categories on my blog I have that part of the loop in its own div with a background image. I'd like to have the background image change based on the category of that post. I believe I can do this in css with a set of conditional tags (something along the lines of if category () echo red.png)
Any ideas of where to start with this or if it is possible?
The site is blog.printstitchandpaste.com and the image to be changed is the little flag/banner behind the category name.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, you can have something like:

```
.category_callout.cat-1-slug {
  background-image: url('category-1-image.jpg');
}
.category_callout.cat-2-slug {
  background-image: url('category-2-image.jpg');
}
```

And so on.

In your theme, where you have your `.category_callout` div, get the categories and echo the slugs. For example:

```
<div class="category_callout <?php foreach( get_the_category() as $cat ) { echo $cat->slug . ' '; } ?>">
```

This will add all the post categories slugs. If you want to use only the first category, do something like:

```
<?php $cat = get_the_category(); ?>
<div class="category_callout <?php echo $cat[0]->slug; ?> ">
```

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category

Comment: Will the php the second bit of code work within the quotes? Also, for the first bit of code, do I need the category numbers or can I just call them cat-slug?

Comment: First bit of code, do you mean the CSS? I don't know your categories names so I just put .cat-1-slug and .cat-2-slug. If your category name is something like "Hello world", the slug will most likely be `hello-world` so you can have this in the CSS: `.category_callout.hello-world`.

I don't understand the question about the php...